# Conditional Split Transformation To Multiple Sheets In SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, excel-2007

I am trying to insert data into three excel sheets from a SQL table based on the condition given in SSIS Conditional Split Transformation.

When i run the package first time, it succeeds but after that i am getting the below error:

```
[Excel Destination [133]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

[Excel Destination [133]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Excel Destination Input" (144)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Excel Destination Input" (144)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Excel Destination" (133) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Excel Destination Input" (144). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

This error is occurring to random excel destination. I am unable to find what is the cause.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to append data to the same excel sheet? If so, you may need to delete and recreate the whole sheet before you start loading the data.

Comment: I have a template file which will copy to another location before loads the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the 3 sheets sequentially.   Attempting to load them simultaneously can cause contention issues.   Reorganize your package so that the sheets are forced to load in order (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3).

Comment: Yes, you are right. SSIS is not supporting the above scenario.